# Select Master records and details belong to it in one Select

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Please consider this records:

tblMaster:

```
   ID           Name            
   ------------------
   1            Ben  
   2            Jack
   3            Sara
```

tblDetails:

```
  ID         MasterID          F1            F2
  ----------------------------------------------           
  1             1              1995          'A'
  2             1              1998          'B'
  3             1              2000          'A'
  4             2              2010          'E'
```

Now I want to Set `tblDetails` property of `tblMaster` to above records.Is it possible do this in one statement?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Please elaborate.

Comment: LINQ to entities should do this when you fetch `tblMaster` including `tblDetails`. If this isn't what you mean you should tell us more.

Comment: I want get query like this: tblMaster.tblDetails.where(r=>r.MasterId = 1).ToList(); but it can be done on the client side, not server.

Answer (score 0):

You Can try the following sql command

```
"Join tblMaster.ID,tblMaster.Name, tblDetails.Master.ID,tblDetails.F1,tblDetails.F2 on tblMaster.ID==tblDetails.ID"
```

Comment: I want do this using linq to entities